# Why isn't java.util.regex.matcher not matching all instances in this string?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have the following code: http://ideone.com/mFUaqG

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegexUtils
{
    private static final Pattern resourceURLCSS     = Pattern.compile("url\\([\'\"](((?!://).)*)[\'\"]\\)");
    private static final Pattern resourceURLHTML    = Pattern.compile("(href|src|url)=[\'\"](((?!://).)*)[\'\"]");

    public static String makeCSSURLsAbsolute(String input, String baseURL)
    {
        Matcher matcher     = resourceURLCSS.matcher(input);
        return matcher.replaceAll("url('"+baseURL+"$1')");
    }
    public static String makeHTMLURLsAbsolute(String input, String baseURL)
    {
        Matcher matcher     = resourceURLHTML.matcher(input);
        return matcher.replaceAll("$1=\""+baseURL+"$2\"");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fixed    = RegexUtils.makeCSSURLsAbsolute("div#header { background-image: url('images/header-background.jpg'); } div#header { background-image: url('images/header-background.jpg'); }", "http://www.google.ca/");
        System.out.println(fixed);

        fixed           = RegexUtils.makeHTMLURLsAbsolute("href=\"wtfguys.css\" href=\"wtfguys.css\"", "http://www.google.ca/");
        System.out.println(fixed);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't do what I expect, which is to replace all occurrences of the regular expression with the string replacement. We are essentially replacing relative URLs in CSS and HTML with absolute URLS. It only seems to replace the first occurrence, giving

```
div#header { background-image: url('http://www.google.ca/images/header-background.jpg'); } div#header { background-image: url('images/header-background.jpg'); }
href="http://www.google.ca/wtfguys.css" href="wtfguys.css"
```

as output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are using regexps that attempt to match both single- and double quoted attribute values. The thing is, you may match a truncated value because none of the two patterns makes sure the opening quote matches the closing. Also, that quote should be missing in the value itself.

So, wrap the opening quote into a capture group, use a backrefrence as the closing delimiter and add the backrefrence as an alternative to the lookahead in the tempered greedy token. Then, fix the replacement patterns since the order of backreferences will change.

```
private static final Pattern resourceURLCSS     = Pattern.compile("url\\((['\"])((?:(?!://|\\1).)*)\\1\\)");
private static final Pattern resourceURLHTML    = Pattern.compile("(href|src|url)=(['\"])((?:(?!://|\\2).)*)\\2");

public static String makeCSSURLsAbsolute(String input, String baseURL)
{
    Matcher matcher     = resourceURLCSS.matcher(input);
    return matcher.replaceAll("url('"+baseURL+"$2')");
}
public static String makeHTMLURLsAbsolute(String input, String baseURL)
{
    Matcher matcher     = resourceURLHTML.matcher(input);
    return matcher.replaceAll("$1=\""+baseURL+"$3\"");
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8XuUOW)

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is greedy. The matcher captures `wtfguys.css" href="wtfguys.css` as `$2`, not `wtfguys.css`. You can use `.*?` or `[^\"]*` instead, since URLs don't have even escaped quotes inside. Reference for this issue explaining several options (including the one mentioned by Wiktor): http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap.

Comment: And the solution might be to make it non-greedy by adding a `?` after `*`.

Comment: No, I think the tempered greedy tokens should be fixed, it is not just about lazy or greedy quantifiers. Else, there would be no `[\'\"]`s around. Another capture group, a backrefrence and an alternative in the negative lookahead are required.

Comment: No need to support escaped sequences, these are not C strings.